# symfony output in kernel.php

Tags: symfony, output, symfony-http-client

**in app.php**

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

**in Kernel.php**

```
 public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        print('test');
        $this->environment = $environment;
        $this->debug = (bool) $debug;
        $this->rootDir = $this->getRootDir();
        $this->name = $this->getName();

        if ($this->debug) {
            $this->startTime = microtime(true);
        }

        $defClass = new \ReflectionMethod($this, 'init');
        $defClass = $defClass->getDeclaringClass()->name;

        if (__CLASS__ !== $defClass) {
            trigger_error(sprintf('Calling the %s::init() method is deprecated since version 2.3 and will be removed in 3.0. Move your logic to the constructor method instead.', $defClass), E_USER_DEPRECATED);
            $this->init();
        }
    }
```

I want to output this code at the browser for learning purposes . I guess it's buffered, but where can I switch it off and output my print at the browser? Or is there a better way through the console?

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "output this code at the browser"?

Answer (score 1):

Not positive I understand the question but if you look in web/app.php then you will see:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

The bootstrap.php.cache file is where the cached (buffered?) copy of the Kernel object lives.  You can either edit the cache file and add your print statements or just not include the cache file:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see :)

Comment: So did this answer your question?  Just curious.

Comment: Yes, and I vote but this message comes: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.